# Starting a chat, including existing comments

Tags: support, chat

There are a few features in Stack Exchange that I can never remember how to do.

How do I move a discussion that has started in an exchange of comments to a chat, while copying the existing discussion to the chat as well?   I've seen it done, and I've even done it myself, but I always struggle to figure out how it's done.

Comment: I think if you click the "move discussion to chat" message once it appears, the SE software should migrate the whole conversation. Not sure how it's done prior to that message appearing

Comment: @KyleKanos there is no way to do so (automatically) prior to that message AFAIK.

Comment: @DavidZ: Moderators can move comments to chat at will though, can't they?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know of such a tool. I looked a way to do it to *this* post. Of course, I seem to miss a lot.

Comment: @dmckee: Ah, it seems I've misunderstood a [recent feature change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976). You can only move comments to chat if there are *too many* comments.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Cool. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @dmckee Well that explains why I thought that I had done it in the past.